# Dealing with two different coordinate systems in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, convert, geometry, format

I'm seeking a function that converts degrees to the following format:

```
POINT(405115.926025391 4543389.4354248)
```

I don't know this format's name, but is there any function to do so?

EDIT ------- > converting SRID

```
WITH currentPoint AS (
    SELECT
        st_transform(st_setsrid(st_makepoint(3.6392182823950043, 37.74446159789074), 900913), 900913) AS point
)
SELECT 
    building.gid
FROM 
    building, currentPoint 
WHERE
    ST_Dwithin(building.geom, currentPoint .point, 10)
```

Answer (score 2):

i dont know but it looks like SRID **EPSG:900913** - Google Map Web Mercator.

you can try this:

```
UPDATE myTable SET  the_geom = ST_Transform(the_geom,900913);

SELECT UpdateGeometrySRID('myTable', 'the_geom', 900913);
```

i have tested your coordinates in any openlayers page with using this and it gives me this result:

```
new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(405115.926025391, 4543389.4354248)
.transform(new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:900913'), new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:4326'));
```

the returned result:

```
POINT(3.6392182823950043 37.74446159789074) { id=    
"OpenLayers_Geometry_Point_865"    
, x=    
3.6392182823950043    
, y=    
37.74446159789074    
, more...}
```

i hope it helps you...

Comment: thanks Aragon for quick response, now this is what I get "transform: couldn't project point"

Comment: check out if you have EPSG:900913 in your spatial_ref. `SELECT proj4text FROM spatial_ref_sys WHERE srid = 900913`;

Comment: yes, I do have this SRID, I've updated my question based on your answer, but still not on the right path, cause I get error, am I making an obvious mistake? thanks

Comment: You need to define your starting point as SRID 4326 and convert it to 900913. It looks like you're doing it the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

There's two obvious errors:

```
st_transform(st_setsrid(st_makepoint(3.6392182823950043, 37.74446159789074), 900913), 900913) AS point
```

It seems, you want to convert from 4326 to 900913, so you have to: 1) create point with ST_MakePoint 2) set it's SRID to 4326 with ST_SetSRID 3) Transform it to 900913 with ST_Transform

```
st_transform(st_setsrid(st_makepoint(3.6392182823950043, 37.74446159789074), 4326), 900913) AS point
```

Probably it's typo (extra space) in

```
ST_Dwithin(building.geom, currentPoint .point, 10)
```

and you mean

```
ST_Dwithin(building.geom, currentPoint.point, 10)
```

BTW, you are looking for buildings, that are within 10 SRID units (lets say 10 meters, to keep things simple) from given point, that's quite a small distance.